# Value errors in KerasRegressor using GridSearhCV

Tags: grid-search, gridsearchcv

I need to find the best parameters that will ultimately inform the best price for a certain number automobile characteristics. The *csv file is attached, so as you can have the exact picture of the problems: [DataAutomobile.csv](https://drive.google.com/file/d/11fDeTljGvngt2FtFC1rWRzds1UW010Rl/view?usp=sharing)

When I compile, I get the following error:

**File "C:\Users\jetta\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scikeras\wrappers.py", line 1127, in set_params
raise ValueError(**

**ValueError: Invalid parameter activ1 for estimator KerasRegressor. This issue can likely be resolved by setting this parameter in the KerasRegressor constructor:`KerasRegressor(activ1=relu)`. Check the list of available parameters with `estimator.get_params().keys()`**

The other messages if I force `activ1 = relu`. Below is just a sample of several similar errors

**ValueError: Invalid parameter neurons1 for estimator KerasRegressor. This issue can likely be resolved by setting this parameter in the KerasRegressor constructor:KerasRegressor(neurons1=100)**

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf 
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras import backend as k
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from tensorflow.keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasRegressor
from scikeras.wrappers import KerasRegressor

base = pd.read_csv('autos.csv', encoding = 'ISO-8859-1')

base = base.drop('dateCrawled', axis = 1)
base = base.drop('dateCreated', axis = 1)
base = base.drop('nrOfPictures', axis = 1)
base = base.drop('postalCode', axis = 1)
base = base.drop('lastSeen', axis = 1)
base = base.drop('name', axis = 1)
base = base.drop('seller', axis = 1)
base = base.drop('offerType', axis = 1)

base = base[base.price > 10]
base = base.loc[base.price < 350000]

auto_values = {'vehicleType': 'limousine', 'gearbox': 'manuell',
           'model': 'golf', 'fuelType': 'benzin',
           'notRepairedDamage': 'nein'}
base = base.fillna(value = auto_values)

auto_predictors = base.iloc[:, 1:13].values
auto_RealPrice = base.iloc[:, 0].values

from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer

onehotencoder = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[("OneHot", OneHotEncoder(), [0,1,3,5,8,9,10])],remainder='passthrough')
auto_predictors = onehotencoder.fit_transform(auto_predictors).toarray()

def auto_CreateNeural(optimizer, loss, kernel_initializer, activation, activ1, activ2, activ3, neurons1, neurons2, neurons3, kernel_ini1, kernel_ini2, kernel_ini3):
    k.clear_session()
    regressor = Sequential([
                   tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = neurons1, activation = activ1, kernel_initializer = kernel_ini1, input_dim=316),
                   tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
                   tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = neurons2, activation = activ2, kernel_initializer = kernel_ini2),
                   tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
                   tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = neurons3, activation = activ3, kernel_initializer = kernel_ini3),
                   tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
                   tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = 1, activation = 'linear')])
    regressor.compile(optimizer = optimizer, loss = loss, kernel_initializer = ['kernel_ini1', 'kernel_ini2', 'kernel_ini3'], activation = ['activ1', 'activ2', 'activ3'],
                      units = ['neurons1', 'neurons2', 'neurons3'], metrics = ['binary_accuracy'])
    return regressor

regressor = KerasRegressor(build_fn = auto_CreateNeural, verbose=0)
auto_parameters = {'batch_size': [350, 500],
              'epochs': [3, 5],
              'optimizer': ['adam', 'Adamax'],
              'loss': ['kullback_leibler_divergence','binary_crossentropy', 'hinge', 'mean_absolute_error'],
              'kernel_ini1': ['random_uniform', 'normal', 'glorot_uniform'],
              'kernel_ini2': ['normal', 'glorot_uniform'],
              'kernel_ini3': ['random_uniform', 'normal'],
              'activ1': ['relu', 'elu', 'tanh', 'softmax'],
              'activ2': ['tanh', 'softmax'],
              'activ3': ['elu', 'softmax'],              
              'neurons1': [100, 158, 200, 316],
              'neurons2': [80, 115, 158, 225, 330],
              'neurons3': [70, 90, 120, 158, 250]}
grid_search = GridSearchCV(estimator = regressor,
                           param_grid = auto_parameters,
                           scoring = 'neg_mean_absolute_error', cv = 2) 
grid_result = grid_search.fit(auto_predictors, auto_RealPrice)

# summarize results
print("Best: %f using %s" % (grid_result.best_score_, grid_result.best_params_))
means = grid_result.cv_results_['mean_test_score']
stds = grid_result.cv_results_['std_test_score']
params = grid_result.cv_results_['params']

for mean, stdev, param in zip(means, stds, params):
    print("%f (%f) with: %r" % (mean, stdev, param))
best_auto_parameters = grid_search.best_params_
best_precision = grid_search.best_score_
```

I am new to neural networks, and despite having read several documentations for the past days, I am completely stuck and cannot go further without help. I need to find the best values for each and all of the variables described in "auto_parameters".

What should I exactly do in the code to get it working properly? If not asking much, a brief explanation of the corrections would be really valuable.

Comment: "Is there anybody out there?" Pink Floyd

Answer (score 1):

The errors in SciKeras could use some work, but what that error is telling you is that every argument here:

```py
def auto_CreateNeural(optimizer, loss, kernel_initializer, activation, activ1, activ2, activ3, neurons1, neurons2, neurons3, kernel_ini1, kernel_ini2, kernel_ini3)
```

Requires a corresponding default value when constructing `KerasRegressor`.
That is, you need to change:

```py
KerasRegressor(build_fn = auto_CreateNeural, verbose=0)
```

To:

```py
KerasRegressor(build_fn = auto_CreateNeural, kernel_initializer=...), activ1=..., ...)
```

Scikit-Learn expects estimators to work both in and out of a pipeline, without those defaults this estimator would behave differently inside and outside of a pipeline (namely, it would not work outside of a pipeline).

Comment: it now says ... `TypeError: auto_CreateNeural() missing 13 positional arguments: 'optimizer', 'loss, 'kernel_initializer', 'activation', 'activ1', 'activ2', 'activ3', 'neurons1', neurons2, 'neurons3', 'kernel_ini1', 'kernel_ini2','kernel_ini3'`

Comment: You have to add all of the parameters. I alluded to this with the `...` but I should have been clearer, apologies.

Here's a runnable MRE of the working version: https://gist.github.com/adriangb/1e69beb15c708544c6e06111be9bc83a

In case the gist gets lost, the relevant section:

```python
regressor = KerasRegressor(
    model=auto_CreateNeural,
    verbose=0,
    optimizer="adam",
    loss="binary_crossentropy",
    kernel_ini1="normal",
    kernel_ini2="normal",
    kernel_ini3="normal",
    activ1="relu",
    ... # you get the idea (running out of chars)
)
```

Comment: A couple other things in your example also need fixing:

1. `loss` and `optimizer` are not arguments to `build_fn/model`. Instead use `compile_kwargs`. See https://www.adriangb.com/scikeras/stable/advanced.html#compile-kwargs
2. You are passing arguments to `tf.keras.Model.compile()` that are not valid. See https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#compile for valid arguments